# How do i see results in developer console

Tags: apex, developer-console

**How do I see the results of the array in developer console**

[image]

My apex class looks like below

```
public class StringArrayTest{
    public static List<String> generateStringArray(Integer n)
    {
        List<String> myArray = new List<String>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<n;i++)
        {
           myArray.add('Test '+i);
           System.debug(myArray[i]);
        }
        return myArray;
    }
}
```

**executing using**

```
StringArrayTest.generateStringArray(5);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see below log section click on `unread` (First log)... and click on debug checkbox

[image]